# static page javascript works normally but not in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a static page with a form.  Right now, all the form should do is show a popup alert that says 'done' when the user clicks the button.  It works as just a normal page, but does not work in rails.  I checked the rails page code, and the javascript file is being sent to the user.  All of the code for the rails app is identical to the static page.  Here is the form code:

```
<form action="#" id="sign-up-now" name="_register">
    <div class="form-header clearfix">
        <h4>Sign Up Now as a:</h4>
        <label for="Freelancer">
            Freelancer
            <input type="radio" name="Freelancer" class="radio" id="freelancer" />
        </label>
        <label for="Employer">
            Employer
            <input type="radio" name="Freelancer" class="radio" id="employer" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-content">
        <input type="text" id="user-mail" name="email" class="field" value="Type Your Email Address Here" title="Type Your Email Address Here" />
        <input type="submit" class="button button-signup" id="signup-home" value="SIGN UP!" />  
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the javascript that acts when the submit button is pressed:

```
(function($){
    $(document).on('ready', function(){
        $('#signup-home').on('click', function(){ //signup-home is the id of the submit button
            alert('done');
        return false; 
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I know the rails view can see the javascript because here is an excerpt from the rails app page source:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/functions.js?body=1"></script>
```

The javascript above is in the functions.js file.  Here is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require users
//= require_tree .
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require cocoon
```

I have also disabled turbo links so i know it is not an issue with that.  How do I get the javascript to work?

Comment: is it possible that `$('.form-content')` is sucking up the event? 

Or what if the form is submitting by default, since thats what the submit button is supposed to do. Have you tried `$('form#sign-up-now').submit(function(){})` instead?

Comment: You are right.  The form is submitting because when I press submit the url changes to: "http://localhost:3000/?email=Type+Your+Email+Address+Here#" but i tried doing your changes and it still submits.

Comment: so `$('form#sign-up-now').submit(function(){return false;})` still allows the form to submit?

Answer (score 0):

These will be loaded in the head of the document, and your JS will execute, try to find anything with the ID `signup-home`, and fail (because it doesn't exist in the DOM yet)

It should work if you make your JS execute after page load

```
$(function(){
  $('#signup-home').on('click', function(){ //signup-home is the id of the submit button
    alert('done');
    return false; 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the DOM is loaded. I just posted part of the js file.  I added the code to the content above.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the javascript you're trying to run is in your `users.js` file... If so, there are a couple things that could be causing this. I believe the `//= require_tree .` line should be at the bottom of your `application.js` file. So, in your case, try changing your `application.js` file to:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require users
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require cocoon
//= require_tree .
```

It could also be a precompile issue... Try first deleting everything in your `public/assets` directory. This will force rails to use the pipeline, not any precompiled stylesheets or javascript. If you are deploying to heroku, you'll need to run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` before your `git add` command.

Comment: Thanks, tried it but it didn't work.  I'm working on my localhost.

Comment: I forgot to mention... Try restarting the server after you make the change to the `application.js` file.

Comment: Thanks, I did that though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your DOM is loaded when the listener is trying to attach?

Your functions.js file should have the click function like so:

```
jQuery(function() {
  $('#signup-home').on('click', function(){ //signup-home is the id of the submit button
    alert('done');
    return false; 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the DOM is loaded.  I just posted part of the js file.  I will add the code to the content above.